# PHP - как сделать merge по key + value?

Tags: php, массивы, php7

Массив:

```
    array(2) {
        [0]=> array(2) {
            ["2020-03-27"]=> int(8)
            ["tags"]=> string(17) "STS; сервис" } 
        [1]=> array(2) {
            ["2020-03-27"]=> int(3)
            ["tags"]=> string(17) "PTP; сервис; тест" }
    }
```

Как лучше собрать новый массив, в котором если такой ключ уже есть (например **['2020-03-27']**), то

1. Объединить элемент массива с ключем `["tags"]`, но если его значение одинаковое - то сделать `merge`, если нет - добавить новые значения.
2. Значение элемента с ключем `["2020-03-27"]` - установить последнее.

Я бы сделал так: проверяем есть ли такой ключ, если есть - обновляем значение , а вот как быть с `["tags"]` пока не пойму лучше.

Т.е должен получиться вот такой массив:

```
    array(1) { 
        [0]=> array(2) {
            ["2020-03-27"]=> int(3)
            ["tags"]=> string(17) "STS; PTP; сервис; тест" }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё немного сложнее, так как значение `tags` у Вас является строкой, и надо сравнивать значения в строке. 
Добавил решение и постарался добавить больше комментариев для понимания работы скрипта:

```php
<?php
$arr = array(
    array(
        "2020-03-27" => 8,
        "tags" => "STS; сервис"
    ),
    array(
        "2020-03-27" => 3,
        "tags" => "PTP; сервис; тест"
    ),
    array(
        "2020-03-17" => 3,
        "tags" => "PTP; сервис; тест"
    )
);

$Result = []; // Сюда запишем результат
foreach ($arr as $val){ // Для каждого элемента массива
    $keys = array_keys($val); // Получаем ключи
    $firstKey = $keys[0]; // Берём первый ключ условно (2020-03-27)
    if ($Result){ // Если есть массив
        $z = explode('; ', $val['tags']); // Разбиваем поле tags по точке с запятой и пробелу, чтобы получить значение
        foreach ($Result as $key=>$item){ // Для каждого элемента массива результата...
            $trig = 1; // проставляем триггер
            $keys1 = array_keys($item); // Получаем так же ключи
            $firstKey1 = $keys1[0]; // берём первый ключ
            if ($firstKey == $firstKey1) { // Проверяем совпадение ключей, если совпадают, то...
                $z1 = explode('; ', $item['tags']); // Разбиваем значение tags
                $temp = array_merge($z, $z1); // Сливаем 2 массива
                $temp1 = array_unique($temp); // Оставляем только уникальные значения
                $tags = implode('; ', $temp1); // Соединем обратно в строку
                $Result[$key]['tags'] = $tags; // Меняем значение в массиве $Result
            } else {
                $trig = 0; // Если ключи не равны, то меняем триггер.
            }
        }
        if($trig == 0){ // Если триггер изменён, то значит ключи не равны, а значит...
            $Result[] = $val; // Добавляем значение в массив
        }
    } else {
        $Result[] = $val; // Если массив $Result пуст, то добавляем значение
    }
}

print_r($Result); // Выводим результат.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$array = [
    [
        "2020-03-27" => 8,
        "tags" => "STS; сервис"
    ],
    [
        "2020-03-27" => 3,
        "tags" => "PTP; сервис; тест"
    ],
    [
        "2020-03-17" => 3,
        "tags" => "PTP; сервис; тест"
    ]
];

$result = [];
foreach($array as &$item) {
    $key     = key($item);
    $hikings = array_filter(
        $array,
         function ($item) use ($key) {
            if (key($item) === $key) {
                return $item;
            }
        }
    );

    $map = $item;
    foreach($hikings as $index => $hiking) {
        $map[$key]   = $hiking[$key];
        $map['tags'] = implode(';', array_unique(array_merge(explode(';', $map['tags']), explode(';', $hiking['tags']))));
        unset($array[$index]);
    }
    $result[] = $map;
}

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Предложу вариант покороче.

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    array(
        "2020-03-27" => 8,
        "tags" => "STS; сервис; 27"
    ),
    array(
        "2020-03-27" => 3,
        "tags" => "PTP; сервис; тест"
    ),
    array(
        "2020-03-17" => 3,
        "tags" => "PTP; сервис; тест; 17"
    )
);
$result = [];
foreach($arr as $element){
    // получаем дату из ключа
    list($date, ) = array_keys($element);
    // если уже есть с такой датой
    if(isset($result[$date])){
        // строим строку
        $tags = $result[$date]['tags'].'; '.$element['tags'];
        // убираем повторы через преобразование в массив и обратно
        $tags = implode("; ",array_unique(explode("; ",$tags)));
    }else{
        $tags = $element['tags'];
    }
    $result[$date] = [
        $date => $element[$date],
        'tags' => $tags
        ];
}
// убираем дату из ключей если нужно
$result = array_values($result);
print_r($result);
```